# LISP Cannot take CAR of T

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to evaluate each atom of a list and see if it's equal to the number provided and remove if its not but I am running into a slight problem.

I wrote the following code:

```
(defun equal1(V L)
     (cond((= (length L) 0))
          (T (cond( (not(= V (car(equal1 V (cdr L))))) (cdr L) )))
     )
)

(equal1 5 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

I obtain the following error

```
Error: Cannot take CAR of T.
```

If I add (write "hello") for the action if true, the following error is obtained:

```
Error: Cannot take CAR of "hello".
```

I'm still quite new to LISP and was wondering what exactly is going on and how could I fix this so I could evaluate each atom properly and remove it if its not, thus the cdr L for the action.

Comment: What variety of Lisp is this?

Comment: I'm unsure but from what I've seen, it's like the generic one to which we only use cond.

Comment: Its whatever I get from Lisp works personal edition

Comment: Common Lisp, then.

Comment: You keep calling `(length L)`, but this is not necessary. You only want to know if your list is empty or not, which is simpler to test (no need to iterate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do to improve this function.

Firstly, let's indent it properly

```
(defun equal1 (V L)
  (cond
    ((= (length L) 0))
    (T (cond
         ((not (= V (car (equal1 V (cdr L))))) (cdr L))))))
```

Rather than saying `(= (length l) 0)`, you can use `(zerop (length l))`. A minor sylistic point. Worse is that branch returns no value. If the list `L` is empty what should we return?

The issue with the function is in the `T` branch of the first `cond`.

What we want to do is

1. remove any list item that is the same value as `V`
2. keep any item that is not `=` to `V`

The function should return a list.

The expression

```
(cond 
  ((not (= V (car (equal1 V (cdr L))))) (cdr L)))
```

is trying (I think) to deal with both conditions 1 and 2. However it's clearly not working.

We have to recall that items are in a list and the result of the equal function needs to be a list. In the expression above the result of the function will be a boolean and hence the result of the function call will be boolean.

The function needs to step along each element of the list and when it sees a matching value, skip it, otherwise use the cons function to build the filtered output list.

Here is a skeleton to help you out. Notice we don't need the embedded `cond` and just have 3 conditions to deal with - list empty, filter a value out, or continue to build the list.

```
(defun equal-2 (v l)
  (cond
    ((zerop (length L))  nil)
    ((= v (car l))  <something goes here>)      ;skip or filter the value
    (t (cons (car l) <something goes here>)))) ;build the output list
```

Of course, this being Common Lisp, there is a built-in function that does this. You can look into `remove-if`...

Comment: Ah so it seems the block <something goes here> would be the recursive call function of v and cdr l to keep descending till the first if block is satisfied

Answer (score 2):

`car` and `cdr` are accessors of objects of type `cons`. Since `t` and `"hello"` are not `cons` you get an error message.

To fix it you need to know what types your function returns and not `car` unless you know that it's a  `cons`

**EDIT**

First off ident and clean up the code.. The nested `cond` are uneccesary since `cond` is a *if-elseif-else* structure by default:

```
(defun remove-number (number list)
  (cond ((= (length list) 0) 
         t)
        ((not (= number (car (remove-number number (cdr list))))) 
         (cdr list))))
        (t 
         nil)))
```

I want you to notice I've added the default behaviour of returning `t` when a consequent is not given as we know `=` returns either `t` or `nil` so it returns `t` when the length is 0 in this case.

I've added the default case where none of the two previous predicates were truthy and it defaults to returning `nil`.

I've named it according to the functions used. `=` can only be used for numeric arguments and thus this will *never work on symbols, strings, etc*. You need to use `equal` if you were after values that look the same.

Looking at this now we can see that the functions return value is not very easy to reason about. We know that `t`, `nil` and `list` or any part of the tail of `list` are possible and thus doing `car` might not work or in the case of `(car nil)` it may not produce a number.

A better approach to doing this would be:

1. check if the list is empty, then return `nil`
2. check if the first element has the same numeric value as `number`, then recurse with rest of the list (skipping the element)
3. default case should make `cons` a list with the first element and the result fo the recursion with the rest of the list.

The code would look something like this:

```
(defun remove-number (number list)
  (cond ((endp list) '())
        ((= (car list) number) (remove-number ...))
        (t (cons ...))))
```

Comment: How would I have car and cdr access the list and not t or hello, Im unsure on why there accessing those two im still quite new at lisp

Comment: Wouldnt the recursion stop instantly if the first value in the list is not equal to the value thus the whole list wouldnt be evaluated?

Comment: @KyleJ Both the second and third term does the same recursion, only that the third does is as the second argument to `cons` to have it be the rest of the list including the first element while the second term doesn't do that since the current element is not to be included.